# Meaning of "little more o’er the merry-o"

Tags: idioms, archaic-language, lyrics, abbreviations

In the lyrics of a song, the text goes

> swing a little more, little more o’er the merry-o

I know the proverb "the more the merrier", but `o'er` is [apparently an archaic form of `over`](http://www.dict.cc/?s=o%27er), which confuses me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is followed by a very similar one, which might help:

> Swing a little more, little more o'er the merry-o
>
> Swing a little more, a little more next to me

"Swing a little more" is the singer telling the girl to keep dancing.  You can ignore the repetition of 'little more' as that's just poetry.

The end of each line is the singer telling her where to dance.  "Next to me" is obvious enough.  As you discovered, "o'er" is an archaic form of "over", but this kind of archaic language often appears in folk music and folk-based music (Flogging Molly play a kind of folk-punk).  So the singer wants her to dance "over the merry-o".

Which brings us to the question of what a merry-o is, and how one dances over it.  But at this point we've left the realms of English and entered 'mouth music'.  Many folk songs include sections of meaningless words and sounds.  A well known example is the line "wack fol di daddy-o" from the song Whiskey In The Jar.

So unless someone else knows better, I would assume that "o'er the merry-o" is a section of mouth music and not intended to mean anything.

Comment: Thanks! So I can consider it sound poetry? I first thought it would be onomatopoeia, but linguists would probably roll their eyes if you called it that.

Comment: Sound poetry is a pretty good description.  I think the official term is non-lexical vocables.  There's a good article on Wikipedia about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-lexical_vocables_in_music  Definitely not onomatopoeia.

Comment: If I were to guess, I'd read "merry-o" as a "merry-go(-round)", perhaps bringing to mind swinging in circles (as one does when dancing with a partner, especially to upbeat, folksy music). But it might just mean nothing and sound good, too.

Answer (score 0):

... the devils dance floor refers to the raised wooden platform of a gallows. swinging should now be obvious.

as for the Merry-O its similar to how Derry-o is just a reference to a derry (or orchard) the word Merry refers to "outside the law", such as Robin Hood's band of  Merry Men, who were brigands.
in this case Over the Merry means to cross the law, or break it. and the "lass" he's singing about it a temptation.

the song has several other references, like the crushed beneath her wave like a ship he could not reach her shore, and the reference to Avalon, from the Arthurian tales, and the apple (the biblical forbidden fruit)

so when you take this whole song into context, it starts to make sense. the previous guy failed to understand that its a shanty song about the Hempen Jig (the death throws of a man suffocating on the end of a rope) and not dirty dancing.

also whack fol di daddio... a drink for my dad... were looking at Irish-American slang from around the late 1840's and through to around 1860. keep in mind that around 1/4 of Irelands population immigrated to America in this time period, and they prettymuch came up with a bunch of slang terms as a mix of irish and american-english